# Converting Object int data members to floating point and dividing appends strange data cout to console

Tags: c++, object, math, output

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but I just can't figure it out. I've created an object with integer data members, and I want to have a member function return the quotient of it's members as a floating point value, which it does. It then appends some additional stuff. The output is below the program, which should run as is.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class Rational
{
public:
    explicit Rational(int = 0, int = 1);
    double getRationalAsDouble() const;
private:
    int numerator;
    int denominator;
};

Rational::Rational(int numerator, int denominator)
{
    if (denominator == 0)
        this->denominator = 1;
    else
        this->denominator = denominator;
    this->numerator = numerator;
}

// *******  Problem Function *********
double Rational::getRationalAsDouble() const
{
    double a = 0.0, b = 0.0;
    a = static_cast<double>(numerator);
    b = static_cast<double>(denominator);
    cout << endl << "a = " << a;
    cout << endl << "b = " << b;
    cout << endl << "a/b = " << (a/b);
}
// ******** End Problem Function ********

int main()
{

    { //Create a new Scope so that I can view Destructor Message, not used here

        Rational c(2, 6);
        int data = 10;

        cout << c.getRationalAsDouble(); // prints rational object c as double, but not really
        cout << "\n\n";
            } // End of Scope
    return 0;
} // end main
```

And here's the output:

```
a = 2
b = 6
a/b = 0.3333332.31196e-317
```

I've been playing around, and if I change the function to have any regular division in it, it works fine. What's really interesting is if I add any output after the ***cout << endl << "a/b = " << (a/b);*** line, that output is handled before (a/b) part of the line. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance for your time.

**Solution:**
The function wasn't returning anything. When the code was changed to:

```
double Rational::getRationalAsDouble()
{
    return static_cast<double>(numerator)/denominator;
}
```

It worked as expected. Thank you **tc.**

Comment: The recommended link does not answer the question. I'm dividing two floating point numbers, and getting the expected value with additional garbage values at the end. I should see `a/b = 0.33333332` without the `.31196e-317` appended to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three problems:

- You want to print endl at the *end* of the line, not the "beginning". Your code ends up doing (effectively) `cout << endl << "a/b = " << (a/b); ... cout << c.getRationalAsDouble(); cout << "\n\n";` which prints the two doubles `0.333333` and `2.31196e-317` next to each other with no space.
- You want (perhaps) `cout << "\n" << endl` instead of `cout << "\n\n"`. `endl` causes the stream to be flushed; plain "\n" might not.
- `Rational::getRationalAsDouble()` is not returning a value. Listen to your compiler warnings.

The fix looks something like

```
double Rational::getRationalAsDouble() const
{
  double a = 0.0, b = 0.0;
  a = static_cast<double>(numerator);
  b = static_cast<double>(denominator);
  cout << "a = " << a << endl;
  cout << "b = " << b << endl;
  cout << "a/b = " << (a/b) << endl;
  return a/b;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe the return was the issue. I originally implemented it as `cout static_cast<double>(numerator)/denominator;`, but obviously the problems were there still, because it didn't return anything. I'm using Dev-C++, which does not warm me if I'm not returning a value. I've slowly been moving over to Visual C++, which is so much better, but I've been having an issue with it today, so just went back to old betsy. Thank you again, I appreciate your time!

Comment: You may have to enable the compiler warning. Dev-C++ appears to compile with GCC; I recommend `-Wall -Wextra -Wformat=2 -Wno-unused-parameter` as a starting point.

Comment: Compilers aren't required to diagnose missing return values (in general, to do this accurately they would have to solve the halting problem). But it is a  nice QoI issue to be able to do it in simple cases like this.

Comment: Great advice, thanks tc., I'll look into it, as long as I'm using Dev-C++ every now and again, may as well have it catch more issues. And, you're so right Matt, I struggled with this for a couple hours before posting. For it to be a return issue just kills me.

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation of `Rational::getRationalAsDouble()` can be simplified to:

```
double Rational::getRationalAsDouble() const
{
   return 1.0*numerator/denominator;
}
```

I think you had everything else there for debugging purposes, and hence are not really needed.